# EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW using JAX-WS

Tags: java, windows, exception

Basically I have a JAW-WS web service. I call this millions of times, in batch, from an external application. After around 20 million calls the application crashes with the error below. I have tried upgrading the java version, trying on different machines and its all the same.

> An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred.
>
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xc00000fd) at pc=0x7c90e8e5, pid=9396,
>   tid=9000
>
> JRE version: 6.0_29-b11  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
>   (20.4-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )  Problematic frame:  C
>   [ntdll.dll+0xe8e5]
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:  U:
>   hs_err_pid9396.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: 
>   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

I have read that `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW` are caused by recursive, or nested function that do not return correctly. I don't think this is the issue my case as I only have one call that does some work and returns. Silly question but is there a way of clearing the stack, maybe I can do this every x hours?

I managed to get a clean installation of server 2008 and the latest JRE. when i run the same application on this machine i get the below message. im sure it better to look at this error than the last as this is the live box the application will be deployed on. Thanks

28-Dec-2011 14:34:58 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getRequestWrap

```
perClass
INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper Class Professional
Services.jaxws.CleanResponse
28-Dec-2011 14:34:58 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getResponseWra
pperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating response wrapper bean Class Professional
Services.jaxws.CleanResponse
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new
native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(Unk
nown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.handle(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Dispatcher.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

This exception means that you have encountered a bug in Java. Java should never encounter an OS-level stack overflow, it should always be throwing its own StackOverflowException instead. All you can do with one of these is try a newer or older JRE, and report it to Oracle.

Comment: oh wow really? Does it mean there is nothing i can do? The only work around i have is to shut the application down after 6 hours and then start it back up again, cron job ot windows scheduler. Is there anything i can to to progrmatically achieve this?

also how do i find out which version of the JRE to use, ie one that does not have this error. Will Oracle tell me once i have submitted the bug?

Comment: go to their bug reporter and see what you see. In general, they are not very helpful. You don't have much choice but to download a few different versions and try experiments. I can't help you very much with the restart stuff, open another question.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this answer will work or not or maybe u already done that. Try to call garbage collector after few iteration, define & use variable in only required scope & assigned null value to them once their usage done.

Comment: also dont keep large data in memory

Comment: i have performed a profile of the application using netbeans and i can see that the GC is being called periodically once the heap is reaching the max 16mb. i have also tired to null the variables just before the web service returns and still not luck :(... thank you for the advice. It does at least help me prove i am on the right tracks in terms of troubleshooting steps.

Comment: would increaseing the heap size not only delay the problem? sorry a code drop is not possible, but i have updated the main post with more information if it helps... Thanks